# Android app using Flash cc 2015

Tags: android

I have built an android app using Flash cc 2015. I am now trying to get this on the play store but keep getting the following error.

> Upload failed You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that expires too soon. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that expires farther into the future. Learn more about signing.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory. You need to sign your app with certificate which is not going to expire too early.

> If you plan to publish your apps on Google Play, **the key you use to
>   sign these apps must have a validity period ending after 22 October
>   2033**. Google Play enforces this requirement to ensure that users can seamlessly upgrade apps when new versions are available.

https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

So you need new certificate with expiration date fulfilling Google Play requirement